# What is a branch in CVS?

Tags: version-control, cvs, branch

What is a branch in CVS?

Comment: Yes, this question is mostly to help google... seeing some other devs asking this with poor results reading it.

Comment: It's going to defeat the purpose if the top-voted answer is just a link to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A branch is copy of the code at a given point in time.

Example:

- You're writing a program, and checking the code into CVS periodically.
- You then make a release of that program to the public.

  - You should make a copy of the code in the state that it was in when you released it into a branch.
- You can then continue developing the code on the trunk.
- If there are some changes that you make on the trunk that you'd like to also be in the released version, you can merge your changes into the branch, and then make a new release from the branch as an update.

This method allows you to keep stable repositories code and really helps with versioning.

Comment: Its also good practice to tag the release when you branch as well. Otherwise it will be difficult to get an exact copy of what you released.